How to create proc macro that accesses associated types
I have trait with associated types and struct that implements it:
trait T {
    type AT1;
    type AT2;
}

struct S;

impl T for S {
    type AT1 = i32;
    type AT2 = f64;
}

I want to create proc macro that takes struct that implements T as input and produces struct each field of which corresponds to associated types of T.
For example:
// this call
super_macro!(S);

// should produce struct like this
struct SuperMacroOutput {
    field_i32: i32;
    field_f64: f64;
}

I want resulting field types to be exact as associated types (i32 and f64), not <S as T>::AT1 and <S as T>::AT2.
Can I create such macro in stable Rust?

No, you can't create such a macro since that would require knowing types and traits, but a macro is just fancy text replacement (very simply speaking)

A macro knowing that info would have to be an attribute on the impl T for S or a function-like macro wrapping it.

Why do you want it? Chances are you can do what you want without that.

@Chayim I write framework that requires generic struct fields of which differ from project to project. So, I created proc macro that users of my framework can use to generate this struct and surrounding boilerplate (user calls macro with types needed for this project as arguments and macro generates struct needed for framework). I've chose this approach to avoid dynamic dispatch (I could avoid this generic struct and store fields needed for particular project in Box<dyn ..>, but I don't want to). That macro works fine. And now I want to add ability to write extensions for my framework.

Extension is any struct that implements trait similar to T trait from original question, the trait has only associated types. Implementation of this trait indicate which type should be added to generic struct for extension to work. And so original question is about adding ability to specify extensions (implementors of Extension trait) in my macro for it to get associated types from Extension imlementation and add them to generic struct alongside types that user specified by hand (not via extension).

@user24125329 That doesn't answer why you can't just name the associated type and need its actual value.

@Chayim I want to avoid duplicate fields in generic struct. I.e. if multiple extensions require same type, I will detect that and add only one field to gengeric struct instead of three

You can do this in a hacky way if you are okay with 'static bounds by wrapping each extension in Option and before initializing or using it comparing its TypeId to all previous extensions.
